# How to ignore joining objects in LINQ Select statement to pull record

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am working on LINQ script/lambda to pull data from objects. There is a joining table/class to connect A and B table/ object.

I have managed to pull the record but it is in the following form

```cs
List<IEnumerable<ValidationRule>>
```

where I want to ignore joining object and simply get `List<ValidationRule>`?

```cs
public static List<ValidationRule> GetValidations(string fieldName, Dictionary<string, DataMappingPolicy> dataMappingPolicies)
{
    List<ValidationRule> validationRules = new List<ValidationRule>();

    var policyValidations = dataMappingPolicies.Where(_ => _.Key == fieldName).Select(_ => _.Value.PolicyValidationRules.Select(_ => _.ValidationRule)).ToList();

    return validationRules;
}
```

`DataMappingPolicy`

```cs
public class DataMappingPolicy
{
    public DataMappingPolicy()
    {
        this.PolicyValidationRules = new HashSet<PolicyValidationRule>();
    }

    public Guid DataMappingPolicyId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PolicyValidationRule> PolicyValidationRules { get; set; }

}
```

`PolicyValidationRule`

```cs
public class PolicyValidationRule
{
    public Guid PolicyValidationRuleId { get; set; }
    public Guid DataMappingPolicyId { get; set; }
    public DataMappingPolicy DataMappingPolicy { get; set; }
    public Guid ValidationRuleId { get; set; } 
    public ValidationRule ValidationRule { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the list from `PolicyValidationRules` to get all `ValidationRule` via [`.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0).

```cs
var policyValidations = dataMappingPolicies
    .Where(_ => _.Key == fieldName)
    .SelectMany(_ => _.Value.PolicyValidationRules)
    .Select(_ => _.ValidationRule)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: in `.SelectMany(_ => _.ValidationRule)` the validationRule object is not available. I can do only `select`

Comment: Hi, can you try to provide `DataMappingPolicy` class to review the structure? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated question with the object

Comment: Hi, sorry that for the mistype for `.SelectMany()`, I had update my answer, the `.SelectMany` come first after `.Where()`, which aim to flatten the `PolicyValidationRules` as description mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Idea on how you can fix your problem.

```
public static List<ValidationRule> GetValidations(string fieldName, Dictionary<string, DataMappingPolicy> dataMappingPolicies)
    {
        List<ValidationRule> validationRules = new List<ValidationRule>();

        var policyValidations = dataMappingPolicies.Where(_ => _.Key == fieldName).Select(_ => _.Value.PolicyValidationRules.Select(_ => _.ValidationRule));

        foreach(var item in policiValidations)
        {
           validationRules.Add(item);
        }

        return validationRules;
    }
```

First remove the the `ToList()` from your code.

Then if `policyValidations` is of type `IEnumerable<ValidationRule>` than you should be able to iterate through the values with a `foreach` statement and add each of them to the list you are trying to return.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectMany` which flattens queries that return lists of lists.

```
var policyValidations = dataMappingPolicies.Where(_ => _.Key == fieldName)
                         .Select(_ => _.Value)
                         .SelectMany(_ => _.PolicyValidationRules)
                         .Select(_ => _.ValidationRule))
                         .ToList();
```